# Create more space between each arrow between nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make the arrows I draw slightly fatter arrows that are also further apart from each node I have?

edit: Is there also a better way then searching TexStackExchange to figuring this stuff on my own (like a popular reference manual?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=1.3,auto=left,every node/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n8) at (1,10) {FGWC / / };
  \node (n7) at (1,8)  {WC / $\rightarrow$ / FG};
  \node (n6) at (1,6)  {WCF / $\leftarrow$ / G};
  \node (n5) at (1,4) {C / $\rightarrow$ / GFW};
  \node (n4) at (1,2)  {CFG / $\leftarrow$ / W};
  \node (n3) at (1,0)  {G / $\rightarrow$ / WFC};
  \node (n2) at (1,-2) {GF / $\leftarrow$ / WC};
  \node (n1) at (1,-4) {/ $\rightarrow$ / WCGF};

\draw [->] 
(n8) edge (n7) 
(n7) edge (n6) 
(n6) edge (n5)
(n5) edge (n4)
(n4) edge (n3)
(n3) edge (n2)
(n2) edge (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `pgfmanual` is IMHO decent, there is also VisualTi*k*Z. You can shorten the arrows with `shorten` and make them thick with `thick`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
  [scale=1.3,auto=left,every node/.style={rectangle,fill=blue!20}]
  \node (n8) at (1,10) {FGWC / / };
  \node (n7) at (1,8)  {WC / $\rightarrow$ / FG};
  \node (n6) at (1,6)  {WCF / $\leftarrow$ / G};
  \node (n5) at (1,4) {C / $\rightarrow$ / GFW};
  \node (n4) at (1,2)  {CFG / $\leftarrow$ / W};
  \node (n3) at (1,0)  {G / $\rightarrow$ / WFC};
  \node (n2) at (1,-2) {GF / $\leftarrow$ / WC};
  \node (n1) at (1,-4) {/ $\rightarrow$ / WCGF};

\draw [-latex,thick,shorten >=1pt,shorten <=1pt] 
(n8) edge (n7) 
(n7) edge (n6) 
(n6) edge (n5)
(n5) edge (n4)
(n4) edge (n3)
(n3) edge (n2)
(n2) edge (n1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]